# GLsizeiptr and GLintptr - function list

Tags: opengl

I would like to check which core OpenGL functions use GLsizeiptr and GLintptr types. Where can I find the full OpenGL function list ? I have check `glspec46.core.pdf` but there is no such list. When GLsizeiptr and GLintptr have been introduced to the core specification ?

Comment: "*When GLsizeptr and GLintptr have been introduced to the core specification ?*" What does that matter?

Comment: [This](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/) has all the functions, but it won't have something like "list all functions with this as parameter type", nor do I imagine any documentation for OpenGL has that kind of filter. I guess you can data mine this page or something?

Comment: I guess your best chance to generate a list of functions using one of these types is to parse the [xml files from the opengl registry](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/xml/gl.xml) yourself.

Comment: @NicolBolas - out of curiostiy, @MudkipHacker, @BDL I can just use `grep`.